# StructureMap 3 break change

Tags: structuremap, structuremap3

The following code not working on StructureMap 3:

```
x.For<Environment>()
    .LifecycleIs(StructureMap.Pipeline.Lifecycles.GetLifecycle(InstanceScope.HttpContext))
    .Use(c => Environment.GetEnvironment("APP"));
x.SelectConstructor(() => new HelpController());
```

InstanceScope.HttpContext not working StructureMap 3

SelectConstructor() not working on StructureMap 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "new" syntax for Lifecycles, which is also available in Structuremap 2, is the following

```
x.For<Environment>()
    .LifecycleIs<HttpContextLifecycle>()
    .Use(c => Environment.GetEnvironment("APP"));
```

EDIT:

The replacement for `SelectConstructor` is now under `PolicyExpression`

```
x.Policies.ConstructorSelector(...);
```

There's a change to the way `ConstructorSelector` works. Best idea is to have a look at the [Test source](https://github.com/structuremap/structuremap/blob/master/src/StructureMap.Testing/Pipeline/ConstructorSelectorTester.cs), to see how it it used.

Comment: This fixed the InstanceScope.HttpContext break change issue. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `SelectConstructor` part of the question. Check my edit for the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you and this link to the test source is super helpful!